# How to run two different projects simultaneously in Angular 7

Tags: javascript, angular

We are working as two teams on an application  with two different work spaces. One work space is main project and another work space was getting exported as module to our private npm repository, From there we are getting that our module through our package.json. One problem we are facing every time is ,If we want to  test the module with main app we are pushing to repo and getting it again and again. By this we are wasting so much time in development phase. Is there any way we can avoid this.

Comment: decent question, but may be a better fit for something like serverfault instead of stackoverflow

Answer (score 0):

Look into using a mono repo. Mono repos were added in Angular 6 and enhanced in Angular 7 where your lib can be in the same project as the main app. You will need to run up a new Angular 7.

I read a good post about it on Reddit the other day but am at work and can't get to Reddit to link to the article. Have a browse of http://reddit.com/r/angular2

Found it: https://nezhar.com/blog/up-and-running-library-development-with-angular-7/

Comment: Yes I already have gone through this  but the problem is the other code is sitting on some other place

Comment: Then you need to go through the painful deployment process you are looking to avoid. The point of the mono repo is so your library and app can be in the same project.